# Преобразовать строку в число

Tags: php, числа, строки

Как при помощи PHP превратить строку в число? При том строка хранится в отдельной переменной. Пробовал так:

```
$var1="1";
$var2=(int)$var1;
echo $var1."<br>".$var2;
```

Но в итоге откладка через `echo` показала, что:

```
1
0
```

То есть `$var2=0`, а почему - не понятно. Объясните и подскажите, пожалуйста!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Во всем виновата Ваша отладка через echo!

echo пытается преобразовать содержимое переменной в строку, что бы вывести на экран. Используйте для отладки var_dump. А еще лучше xdebug.

Что бы убедиться в этом попробуйте сделать так:

```
$a = new stdClass();
echo $a;
```

Получите `Fatal error` с текстом:

```
Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string
```

Comment: > Во всем виновата Ваша отладка через echo! echo пытается преобразовать содержимое переменной в строку

Ну число оно должно нормально преобразовывать?

А еще меня пугает ваше уважение **666**

Comment: Смотря какое число. Так echo выведет не совсем то что ожидается...

    $a = 0123;
    echo $a; // выведет 83
    
    $a = 0.12300;
    echo $a; // 0.123

Имхо, отладка через echo плохой подход...

Вы суеверны?))

Comment: > $a = 0123;
> echo $a; // выведет 83
я лично это и ожидал:).

Comment: это же хорошо :)

Comment: > отладка через echo плохой подход...

согласен

> Вы суеверны?))

есть немного )))

>$a = 0123;
>echo $a; // выведет 83

но если:

    $a = (int)"0123";
    echo $a; // выведет 123

> $a = 0.12300;

но тут, по-моему, он должен в любом случае отбросить 2 нуля, и в отладке, и в var_dump

Comment: но тут, по-моему, он должен в любом случае отбросить 2 нуля, и в отладке, и в var_dump
точно, плохой пример )

Answer (score 5):

```
intval($var1) //получает целочисленное значение переменной.

floatval ($var1) //получает значение переменной - число с плавающей точкой
```

Comment: то же самое - можно скайп или ICQ? скину URL на вывод

Comment: @Semen Savenko кстати говоря и Ваш вариант работает http://s5.hostingkartinok.com/uploads/images/2013/08/911b2221581bb7212fe015558f503c6b.png возможно у Вас очень старая версия php? <4